# What are the approaches we have to move content types and their fields from test to production

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, migration, pnp-powershell, pnp

We have 2 SharePoint online tenants, Test and Production. and we have some content types (which have columns) inside the Test tenant that we want to move to the production. so what are the available options for us? we do not have any migration tool. can we do this using custom code or PnP scripts?

Regards

Comment: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPContentType.html

Comment: @CallumCrowley thanks for the reply.. i already read this link, but it does not show how to move CTs and their fields, it show how to create new CTs..

Comment: Just fetch the content type from the other tenant: https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPContentType.html

Comment: @CallumCrowley after fetching can i Set the fetched data?

Comment: You can fetch the content type and then use that information to use Add-PnPContentType